# Filter date to default JavaScript format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I'm receiving a `JSON` response of a date property in the form of `yyyy-MM-dd`. 
I want to convert this into the default JavaScript format as - `Mon Jun 13 2016 16:35:48 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` using Angular.js

I went through the date filter documentation at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date 
.It shows the "fullDate" format along with a timezone that we can add, but it isn't exactly the format defined above.

Is there a way to do this in angular using the `$filter` object?

Comment: Strictly, the "default JavaScript format" is whatever is returned by *Date.prototype.toString* in Mozilla browsers. The language specification ([*ECMA-262*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.tostring)) says that it is entirely implementation dependent, so any human readable string will do. Do not expect the same result from all browsers or ECMAScript implementations as they differ (e.g. Chrome and IE return quite different strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create date variable from string you receive i.e.:

```
$scope.date = new Date('2016-06-13'); // or new Date(String(variableWithDate));
```

Now you can use any date filter i.e.:

```
$scope.format = "EEE MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss 'GMT'Z '(Eastern Daylight Time)'";
```

HTML:

```
{{date | date: format}}
```

Check it working in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5se8g1e/)

Comment: This works, but is there a way I can add the time zone and (Eastern Daylight Time) within the $scope.format?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom filter

```
angular.module("yourApp").filter('displayJSDate', function(){
  return function(inputString){
    //inputString is formatted mm-dd-yyyy
    var myDate = new Date(inputString);
    //manipulate the date obj if you want
    //no manipulation will result in Mon Jun 13 2016 16:35:48 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) like string
    return String(myDate);//explicit cast to a string

  }
})
```

in the mark down then all you need is to use this filter with the '|' syntax

Comment: No need to do `String(myDate)`, since Date objects come with a direct `toString` method, so you can just `return myDate.toString()`, which is what happens behind the scenes anyway.

Comment: Note that when parsed using the Date constructor, '2016-06-13' will be treated as GMT and represents '2016-06-13 00:00:00Z'. In the US Eastern Daylight Time time zone the offset is -0400, so in that time zone it is '2016-06-12 20:00:00-0400', so not 13 June. Also, the result of *Date.prototype.toString* varies quite a bit between browsers.